# HoverIntent query not working (wildcard selectors and more)

Tags: jquery

I want to make a dropdown menu for  my website with jquery... a couple of problems occur:

1. The wildcard doesnt seem to work
2. It won't select it's children with ul.

HTML:

```
<li class="px6RANDOM">
    <a href="LINK">
        <span>Disclosure</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="subMenu">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("li.px\\S*").children("ul").hide();

    function show() 
    {
        $(this).children("ul").show();
    }
    function hide() 
    {
            $(this).children("ul").hide();
    }

    $("li.px\\S*").hoverIntent({
        sensitivity: 1, 
        interval: 50,   
        over: show,     
        timeout: 1000,  
        out: hide
    });

});
```

What am I doing wrong? The selector seems to be in order and the children function as well!

I'm a jquery/javascript newbie but want to learn. Please help!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue):

```
$("li[class^='px']")
```

As for show and hide: even when the selectors will work, `this` isn't defined as you expect. Try adding it as an argument for the functions, or remove the functions and inline the code.

Comment: Ah, me bad..... Is there a good definition somewhere on how the scope of this is explained?

Comment: Well, that depends. jQuery is doing an effort to make sure `this` is right when we expect it, but there's no guarantee the plugin you're using does the same (probably does, though). `this` is a JavaScript feature (not just jQuery), and can be used in many ways.